# Atlasboard with Angular2 and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, atlasboard

I am new to using Atlasboard and wondering if there is a way to use Angular2 and Typescript for creating new dashboards, widgets and jobs?

I'll appreciate some help, google hasn't helped so far.

Regards,

Nas